# Continuous functions. Second norm

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, normed-spaces, vector-analysis

Let  $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be continuous. I need to prove that  $\left \| \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \right \|_{2}\leq \int_{a}^{b}\left \| f(x)) \right \|_{2}dx$.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure how to start this proof...

Comment: This is the triangle inequality. See [Minkowski's integral inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: @TooOldForMath: ok, but what would be the intermediate term?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_{n,i}),
$$
where $t_{n,i}=a+i(b-a)/n$, and 
$$
\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_{n,i})\Big\|_2\le \sum_{i=1}^n \|f(t_{n,i})\|_2,
$$
due to the triangular inequality. But
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \|f(t_{n,i})\|_2=\int_a^b\|f(x)\|_2\,dx,
$$
etc...

Comment: The "Clearly" part here is because $f$ is continuous.  The same proof will work for Riemann integrable $f$.  But, in fact, the result in question holds for Lebesgue integrable $f$ as well...